# Refresh the current page from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I searched here lot of question related to **refresh current page** in jquery mobile but mine is slightly differ from others. I **enter some values is popup** when the **popup closes i need to refresh the current page**(that is the popup values should be render in current page).

Here is the sample what i tried:

```
localStorage.setItem("name","tiger");
$(document).on("click","#save",function(){
        $("#openpopup").popup("close");
        localStorage.setItem("name","lion");
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1",{
        allowSamePageTransition : true,
                  transition : 'none',
                  showLoadMsg : true,
                  reloadPage : true
        });
    });


$(document).on("pageshow","#page1",function(){



    if(localStorage.getItem("name")){
        $("#name").val(localStorage.getItem("name"));
    }
});
```

Here is the sample [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/2/)

**Note*** The fiddle is for just reference my actual code is to store in sqlite after get the values in sqlite and refresh the current page.

Comment: Actually I don't know, how do you make your app . If you are using SPA (Single Page Application) design, then you need to ajax call on popup close, that update your entered values. If you are not using SPA then you can use location.href = 'your_page.html'.

Comment: @Ved i am using SPA...

Comment: Here you can use $.ajax function for post and get data.. see api.jquery.com

Comment: @Ved actually popup is opened and enter some values the need to update the entervalues in current page..i don't how to do this...The DOM is not refreshed...here i got the page refresh http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/3/

Comment: See this : http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/4/

Comment: You can also set in localStorage.

Comment: oh @Ved nope...not like that...i already said na...the fiddle is just a demo..my app has lot a texts in popup and need to store in sqlite after popup close then only the page need to refresh...values are render from sqlite.......

Comment: consider i have table with 3 rows when popup opens and fill some values then the table row is increased to 3 to 4 like wise..

Comment: the actual problem is the table row increases to 7 not 4 and again open popup it shows old values..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61955/discussion-between-ved-and-anu).

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem set allowSamePageTransition and transition.

Like

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page1",{
allowSamePageTransition : true,
          transition : 'none',
});
```

Here is  [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcLdkt0w/3/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the transition values. for example.....transition: '3secs', '4secs', etc etc.

Are you asking why your pages won't start restart after the slide show is done? If so, you might need to change the transition properties, and setInterval function on last page transition. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: transition is for like pop,slide... not to set time ..can you provide the fiddle..Please go through the Q once again..